# WSDL dont generate stub code for android (devicemgmt.wsdl)

Tags: android, maven, wsdl, stubs

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

Have eclipse adt, java jdk and maven installed

1.Have the pom.xml

2.Have the onvif.xsd

3.Have the devicemgmt.wsdl

4.Declare de ambiente variables for java JDK(JAVA_HOME), Maven(M2_HOME) and For sdk(ANDROID_HOME)

5.Create a folder WSDL in eclipse (in an android application project), and put the file onvif.xsd and devicemgmt.wsdl inside. Dwvicemgmt.wsdl have in the end of the file declared the ip. 
*soap:address location="http://59.124.49.22:8083/onvif/device_service"*

6.In CMD go to the folder of the projet and run the comand mvn generate-sources eclipse:eclipse

The projet and the pom.xml, devicemgmt.wsdl and onvif.xsd is in this link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xd8byoh9ebqoiuv/devicemgmt.rar?

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?
It's expeted that the comand mvn generate-sources eclipse:eclipse generate some code in the folder descripted in the pom.xml (TARGET folder).

What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?
windows 7 32bit
jdk 1.6.0.45
maven 3.0.5-bin

Please provide any additional information below.

I followed this tutorial(https://code.google.com/p/android-soap-enabler/wiki/FiveMinutesTutorial) but with a diferent .wsdl, and i have put all the jar's that eclipse need.
I also have a problem that when i refresh the project after run mvn generate-sources eclipse:eclipse, /gen already exists but is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it.

I tried to run with the tempconvert.wsdl, and everything runs ok, but with the devicemgmt.wsdl dont generate nothing.

Answer (score 1):

See here: 
http://www.coderanch.com/t/562144/Web-Services/java/Generating-client-code-wsdl-file

You can generate the service stub code i.e. with wsimport from $JDK/bin - with this you are able to see more errors

but i guess your problem is that the devicemgmt.wsdl not contains the service declaration itself so before generating stubs you must put end of this wsdl something like this:

```
<wsdl:service name="DeviceService">  
            <wsdl:port name="DevicePort" binding="tds:DeviceBinding">  
                <soap:address location="http://localhost/onvif/device_service"/>  
            </wsdl:port>  
</wsdl:service>
```